# Django DRF - Access to field ForeignKey instance inside a custom serializer validator method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-model-utils, django-organizations

I'm currently having a bit of a conceptual headache over how best to reference the instance of a ForeignKey field inside a custom serializer validator method ...

To give an overview of the system. I have the following "`Candidate`" model, the imporant fields for this question are the `user`, `job`* and `status` fields.

```py
from model_utils.fields import MonitorField, StatusField
from model_utils import Choices

class Candidate(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ...

    STATUS = Choices(
        'matched',
        'approached',
        'invite_rejected',
        'invite_accepted',
        'reviewed',
        'interview_scheduled',
        'hired',
        'rejected'
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    job = models.ForeignKey('jobs.Job', related_name='candidates', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ... 

    status = StatusField(default='matched')

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Candidate, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `status` field for the `Candidate` can only be "updated" to a given value based on who they are, and what they're attempting to update the status to. Effectively, my outlined logic is as follows inside the serializer:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .candidates.models import Candidate

class CandidateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_status(self, value):
        user = self.context['request'].user

        if user.is_anonymous:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The requester must be logged in to make a change to the status field")

        # Ensure status value is in valid list of statuses
        if value not in [
            'matched',
            'approached',
            'invite_rejected',
            'invite_accepted',
            'reviewed',
            'interview_scheduled',
            'hired',
            'rejected'
        ]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The value provided does not match the prefedined status list")

        # Only the candidate owner can update to certain statuses?
        if value in [
            'invite_rejected',
            'invite_accepted',
        ]:
            if not self.user == user:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("You don't have the correct permission to update the status")

        if value in [
            'matched',
            'approached',
            'reviewed',
            'interview_scheduled',
            'hired',
            'rejected'
        ]:
            if user.is_anonymous or not self.job.organisation.is_admin(user) or not self.job.organisation.is_member(user):
                raise serializers.ValidationError("You don't have the correct permission to update the status")

        return value
```

That is to say, I can obtain the "`user`" doing the updating or creation of the `Candidate` model through the API from the serializer's `self.context['request'].user`.

I'm also checking that this `user` is at first, not anonymous.

What I want access to is the `job` field for the above serializer.

I'm thinking the "`job`" attribute for the serializer ... is accessible via `self.job`.

However, I'm thinking that this is going to return the primary key of the `Job` instance.

So...I wouldn't have access to the `organisation` attribue on the self.job field, because it is not technically an instance of the `Job` model:

```py
user = self.context['request'].user

...

if not self.job.organisation.is_admin(user) or not self.job.organisation.is_member(user):
                raise serializers.ValidationError("You don't have the correct permission to update the status")
```

***So, my question is, how should I correctly reference the `Job` instance associated to the `Candidate` I'm trying to reference?***

***N.B.** It's worth noting that the "`job`" field itself references a "`Job`" model, and this Job model in turn has a field of organisation which links to an organisation as outlined in the `django-organizations` package (reference here: https://github.com/bennylope/django-organizations/ if needed)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`candidate = Candidate.objects.get(id=instance.pk)`

`job = Jobs.objects.filter(candidates__pk=candidate.pk)`

You need to retrieve the job instance from a query, then you can use it as you want. For more complex things you can look at `get_serializer_context(self)`then you can pass attributes to the serializers as kwargs..
Difficult to say more without viewing the whole stuff and the view